# Storing arrays with different lengths in a loop on Python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

It's a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987908/storing-arrays-in-python-for-loop), just that i'm reading different files in a loop, then saving specific data on a np array, but they can be different lengths. When i pass to the next iteration, this data will delete and overwrite data from the next file. I can't use the answer from the link because the size of the array can change and i can't know the length.

Is there a way to save each array so i can use it later (without saving it as a file in my computer).

Comment: So why can't you use a list to store a list of arrays? Like, each loop iteration, create a new array, and append it to the list. Why not just do that?

Comment: Can i do it even though its different lengths? i got an error trying it out and i tought it was because of the lengths. EDIT: It worked as RandomDavis said, the error was something else and im dumb, sorry and thanks

Comment: Glad that worked. You can answer your own posts on here if you want, so you can share a [mre] of what fixed the issue if you think that'll be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE1 = filename
FILE2 = filename 

file1 = open(FILE1, 'r')
lines1 = file1.readlines()
file2 = open("FILE2", 'r')
lines2 = file2.readlines()
file2.close()

lines = lines1 + lines2
lines = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in lines]
```

Comment: not only does this not answer the question, this code would raise an error and doesn't correctly do what it seems to be trying to do

Comment: I posted wrong code (I have testing doc with all attempts saved), fixed it

Comment: yeah, this still doesn't answer the question

Comment: Alright, then I don't really understand the question. Can you explain what he's asking please?

Comment: where in your code do you show how to add numpy arrays to a list? You just show how to make a list of lines from a text file (not even using best-practices like using a with statement, and using `readlines` which is an archaic part of the API). If that was the question, then this would be a clear duplicate